# how to display multiple posts under the same date without repeating the same date in the loop (php)

Tags: php

I want to display the date above the array of posts without the date repeating for posts which have the same date.

i.e.

12/3/2018 
post 
post 
post

instead of :

12/3/2018 
post

12/3/2018 
post

12/13/2018 
post

```
<?php global $connection;
$query = "SELECT posts.post_timestamp, posts.post_id, posts.post_title FROM locations, posts WHERE posts.post_location=locations.id && id=$id "; //Display posts for selected location
$select_posts = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_posts)) {
    $post_id = $row['post_id'];
    $post_title = $row['post_title'];
    $post_timestamp = $row['post_timestamp'];

?>

<h4><?php echo date( "l, d F Y", strtotime($post_timestamp));?></h4> //Display date for all posts with the same date
<h1><a href="post.php?post_id=<?php echo $post_id ;?>"><?php echo $post_title ;?></a></h1> //Print post title

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to keep track of the timestamp and only print it when it changes

```html
<?php global $connection;
$query = "SELECT posts.post_timestamp, posts.post_id, posts.post_title FROM locations, posts WHERE posts.post_location=locations.id && id=$id "; //Display posts for selected location
$select_posts = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
$keepTimestamp = "";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_posts)) {
    $post_id = $row['post_id'];
    $post_title = $row['post_title'];
    $post_timestamp = $row['post_timestamp'];
 //
 if ($keepTimestamp != $post_timestamp){
  $keepTimestamp = $post_timestamp;
 ?>
<h4>
  <?php echo date( "l, d F Y", strtotime($post_timestamp));?>
</h4> //Display date for all posts with the same date
<?php } ?>
<h1>
  <a href="post.php?post_id=<?php echo $post_id ;?>">
    <?php echo $post_title ;?>
  </a>
</h1> //Print post title
<?php } ?>
```